# How to create custom Dialogbox with scrollable items in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, dialog

I wanted to create dialogbox as below picture. When I click on the item, it won't go anywhere until I click 'OK'.
[image: Confirmation Dialogbox with scrollable list items.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try below code:**

get array from resource(you can use arraylist or any array)

```
final String[] mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hours_array);
```

for alert dialog

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setSingleChoiceItems(mTestArray, 0, null)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.txt_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.txt_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // do nothing

                                }
                            })
                            .show();
```